# A tangible example of Persistent Layer and its difference with DAL layer?

Tags: c#, .net

I read about Persistent layer but i couldn't understand it.So, what is Persistent layer in depth? Can you give me an example in a simple application? 
What is the difference between this layer and data access layer?

Comment: Yes. I read all of them but it was not very tangible. I asked this question to have a better answers. Habib, nowadays this is my main question about Stackoverflow, "what i should do when a question already exist but the answers are not satisfying for me?" should i not ask a new question about it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you misheard.  The phrase is 'persistence layer' and it is the part of your application responsible for storing/retrieving data from a filesystem or DB or some other form of 'persistent' storage

Comment: So, what is the difference between persistence layer and Data Access Layer?

Comment: @user3054287 - Tomato vs _tomato_